# Actions and Recommendations - available in experience cloud?

Tags: visual-workflow, quickaction, experience-cloud

I have a client who wants to guide their experience cloud users through a structured/rules-based data entry process. Depending on the state of the record, different types of actions might be indicated.

This process could last weeks for a single record before the record gets submitted for consideration.

Internally, actions and recommendations seems to offer a lot of the structure and guidelines that be valuable.  Am I correct in my conclusion that actions and recommendations wouldn't be available to experience cloud users, particularly if the list of suggested actions needs to vary depending on the record's state?

Answer (score 1):

[Suggested Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_suggested_actions_component.htm&type=5) is a feature that is designed for External users like Experience cloud users.

Other ways to solution would be to use [Salesforce Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did some looking and Suggested Actions does look very useful but may not be robust enough for my use case without a lot of changes to the data model (much of the suggestions would be driven by the state of 1-10 different related child records).  Flows is probably a closer fit, though the client does have Vlocity, so maybe omniscript will be easiest.